# Javascript v3 Fusion Table Layer - ROWID in where clause

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Please excuse me if this has been addressed elsewhere; I did search but couldn't find anything on this specific topic.  Basically, can the ROWID be used in the where clause 
of a fusion query using the Javascript v3 api, e.g.:

```
    var locationLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({ 
       query: { 
           select: 'Address', 
           from: 3349066, 
           where: "'ROWID' in ('2076','2077',....)" 
       } 
   }); 
   locationLayer.setMap(map);
```

This query works with a where clause that does not include ROWID,but 
maybe there's something wrong with my syntax?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: According to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/fusion-tables-users-group/siw7Uqtc0HA it's not yet possible to use ROWID with the FusionTablesLayer.

Answer (score 1):

just to let everyone know, I received this response from Google regarding using the ROWID in the where clause in the maps API:

April 6, 2012

Hi [Abram],

No, I don't think the rowid filter works in the Maps API. Feel free to
open a feature request:

http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/list

Cheers,
Kathryn